# Combining a colour ramp with different shape symbols in AGOL

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I'm trying to replicate functionality from ArcMap, an example below. I have symbolised my data in two levels, shape based on property type (residential vs commercial) and then also a colour ramp based on another field:

[image]

In AGOL I can have my two symbol types separate, but if I try to have both it only offers me 'Types and Size' as a symbol style. What I want ideally is 'Types' as well as 'Colours and Amounts'.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this might work:

[image]

In this example I chose to "Types (unique symbols)" and use my type attribute to style the layer with different symbols in exactly the same color.  Then, in style options I varied the transparency based on the quantitative attribute.

[image]

Otherwise, I cannot see any way to adjust color based on that second attribute.